# I have a piclist field name status and i want that when “Declined” is selected, then Status Date is auto populated to “today

Tags: workflow, configuration

I have a pick list field name status and i want that when “Declined” is selected, then Status Date is auto populated **Today**.

Comment: I have a piclist field name status and i want that when “Declined” is selected, then Status Date is auto populated to “todays date

Comment: Have you tried to create workflow and field update ?

Comment: no i didn't can you please help me with workflow thanks for help

Comment: Why don't you just google it. He already gave you a hint to look for. Search for Workflow field updates.

Comment: check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHdqKvio8P0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create workflow rule on that object.

Go to setup > create > workflow & approvals > workflow rule > continue > new Rule > select 'object' that contains the status field > Give rule name > select evaluation criteria according to your needs > under criteria select status in field, equals under operator and Declined under value.

Now click Save & Next.

Now we will create an update field task.

Click on Add workflow action drop-down, select new field update

Give any name, unique name would be automatically generated

In field to update select Date field > under Data options select use a formula to set the new value>

Click Show Formula Editor

Double click 'today' function from the right side of all function categories.

Click on save.

Now Click on Done.

Now click on Activate

its done..!

Thanks...!